# C++ - Tab control - & character

Tags: visual-c++, tabcontrol

I'm creating several tabs in my project, and when I use '&' char it isn't displayed as it should be.
For example:

> "Tab &1" -> number is underlined

So I figured that I could use:

> "Tab &&1" -> and that result in "Tab &1"

I could add additional '&' manually, but I don't know if there are any more chars that don't work straight forward.
I didn't found any reference on my problem and tab names in my project aren't static.

Here is what I do on WM_CREATE:

```
RECT rcClient;
GetClientRect(hwnd, &rcClient);
TabControl = CreateWindow(WC_TABCONTROL, "",    WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_VISIBLE,0, 0, rcClient.right, rcClient.bottom,  hwnd, (HMENU)0, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);

TCITEM tie;
tie.mask = TCIF_TEXT;
tie.pszText = "Tab &&1";
TabCtrl_InsertItem(TabControl, 0, &tie);
```

Comment: Include your main() code, so we can see the context in which you are trying to use this. We will get a better idea of what you are doing that way.

Comment: C++ has no standard "tabcontrol". So you're going to have to explain what library you're using.

Comment: Unless your library has a way to turn automatic accelerator keys off, you'll just have to do the replacement dynamically whenever you set the tab name.

Comment: There is no any kind of library, its WinAPI.
I've added code how I create Tab control now.

Comment: Give three ampersands a try, e.g. `tie.pszText = "Tab &&&1";` I remember seeing this somewhere...

Comment: That make one '&' and then underlined '1'

Comment: Perhaps it's the digit that's messing it up. Place a space between the `&` and the `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, Unicode is a mountain of special characters, have some fun googling "zalgo".

But the behavior of the & character, and just that particular one, is nailed down as special in the [DrawTextEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) winapi function.  Note the DT_HIDEPREFIX option, explicitly dedicated to controlling the behavior of strings containing the & glyph.  Not an accident, accurately underlining a single character is ridiculously difficult if you have to do it yourself.

Beyond zalgo there's not that much to worry about.  Control characters can be a bit flaky, like "\t" and "\n", you never really use them by accident.  And above all, if there's an accident then you'll see it rather quickly :)

Comment: Thank you! I've made tiny function that adds additional &.